# Most efficient way to compare all collision boxes?

Tags: c++, collision-detection, game-physics

I'm trying to come up with a collision algorithm for my game but am struggling on the method of implementing it. I have a collision box object which contains all the relevant collision data, then a vector of `CollisionBox*` in my game object to handle every collider.

However my method requires calling the same function 4 times for each collision, and the nested loops guarantee that the same collisions will be checked multiple times before the loop is done, and this is called every frame so will be very poor on performance. Here is what I have wrote

```
void Game::CheckCollisions() {
  vector<CollisionBox*>::iterator it;
  for (it = colBoxes.begin(); it != colBoxes.end(); ++it) {
    //for each box - compare the 4 corner points with every other box , only compare different collision layers
    Vector3 boxPos = (*it)->mModel.GetPosition();
    for (vector<CollisionBox*>::iterator it_2 = colBoxes.begin(); it_2 != colBoxes.end(); ++it_2) {
      if ((*it) != (*it_2) && (*it)->colLayer != (*it_2)->colLayer && (*it)->isActive && (*it_2)->isActive) {   
        IsPointInside((*it)->tl, *(*it_2)); //tl  
        IsPointInside((*it)->tr, *(*it_2)); //tr
        IsPointInside((*it)->bl, *(*it_2)); //bl
        IsPointInside((*it)->br, *(*it_2)); //br    
      }
    } 
  }
}

bool Game::IsPointInside(const DirectX::SimpleMath::Vector3& point, CollisionBox& box) {
  return (point.x >= box.bl.x && point.x <= box.tl.x) &&      
    (point.y >= box.bl.y && point.y <= box.tl.y);           
}
```

Comment: Instrument your code for performance measurement to find the bottlenecks. It's hard to tell what should be changed given that detailed and narrow context.

Comment: For example, you may try that the first `it_2` box  is current `it` box (or the nex one), to avoid performing redundant tests.

Comment: If the collision boxes are not all stacked in a small area of the game world, you may want to divide your map into a grid of, for example, 200 * 200 tiles (total 40,000 tiles). Then you could maintain for every grid tile a list of all collision boxes that touch that grid. That way, if you want to determine all collisions with a certain collision box, all you have to do is compare that collision box with the list of collision boxes in the grid tiles that the collision box is touching. You will no longer have to compare with all collision boxes in the game world.

Comment: The method described in my previous comment is only meaningful if not all collision boxes are stacked in a small area of the game world. If they are, then you might want to use an [R-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) instead.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to improve this code for performance.

First, the best would be to put your collision data together, in a contiguous manner. Your vector should contain the minimum required to test the collision. You can use [SOA instead of AOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AoS_and_SoA) if that helps.

Then your collision algorithm is incorrect. You are not checking if the shape overlap, but it the shape has a vertex inside the other. This don't cover such collisions:

```
        o----o
   o----|    |---o
   |    |    |   |
   o----|    |---o
        o----o
```

As you can see, no vertices are inside the other polygon, but definitely collide.

Also, your data is incorrect in the sense that it contains much more data than needed. To represent an align box in memory, you only need two vectors:

```
Top left
   o--------|
   |        |
   |        |
   |--------o Bottom right
```

Then implementing the AABB collision (in 2D or 3D) becomes quite simple.

```
auto aabb_intersect(CollisionBox const& a, CollisionBox const& b) noexcept -> bool {
    return (
        (a.tl.x <= b.br.x && a.br.x >= b.tl.x) &&
        (a.tl.y <= b.br.y && a.br.y >= b.tl.y) &&
        (a.tl.z <= b.br.z && a.br.z >= b.tl.z)
    );
}
```

To upgrade the performance further, you'll need other methods such as space hash partitioning, Quadtrees/Octrees or other method.

If you want performance, always measure and identify the bottlenecks.